# What's the correct way to install Django on mac

Tags: python, django, macos

My mac has 2.7 python. I downloaded the latest version which is 3.5. Next I installed pip. I then tried to install Django, but when I do I am thrown the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
        root=options.root_path,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
        **kwargs
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
        self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
        isolated=self.isolated,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
        clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 310, in clobber
        ensure_dir(destdir)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 71, in ensure_dir
        os.makedirs(path)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    OSError
```

It looks like its' still pointing to the 2.7 version of python how Can I fix that?

Comment: looks like permission error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) No need to mess the system python or use sudo to run pip.

Comment: followed your advice but how do I get it to use python3? the highest available in the bin iis 2.7

Comment: Just install virtualenv scripts and create virtualenv with additional parameter `-p python3.5`. That will create environment using other python version than default.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow instruction in [this tutorial](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/07/install-python3-on-mac-os-x-and-use-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper.html) and make a virtualenv with python3 then point your django python interpreter to it.

Answer (score 0):

try using pip3 instead of pip.